# Turning a list into a set of coordinates [Haskell]

Tags: haskell

I am a starting out programmer and have my first few programming classes. We started off with functional programming, in this case using Haskell. I've managed to complete a few assignments already, but seem to have gotten stuck in one point and was hoping to get some help with it.

In order to not bore you with the entire code, my program right now is extracting a list of commands from a text file. I need to turn this list into a set of coordinates. What I mean is something along the lines of:

```
function :: [String] -> (Int, Int, Char)
```

where the function will receive, for example, the list ["0 0 N"] and output the coordinates and direction (0, 0, N).

I tried doing:

```
function [x y o] = (show x, show y, read o)
```

which would work if it were just Integers. I can't seem to get the Char part to work. I appologize if it's such a noobie question, but bear with me, please, I'm really new to all of this.

Thank you and best regards!

Comment: Have you tried reading all of the parts? :) `show` is a **counterpart** of `read`. What you want is essentially *parsing* the string. If it's already tokenized, then `f [x,y,o] = (read x, read y, read o)` should do the trick. (note the commas)

Comment: Is your input a list of `String`s or a single `String` = a list of `Char`s?

Comment: I did try reading the parts as you have layed out - `infRobot [x,y,o] = (read x, read y, read o)`. But when I attempt using the function in ghci, I get the following:
`infRobot ["0 0 S"]
*** Exception: tarefa2teste.hs:19:1-43: Non-exhaustive patterns in function infRobot`

Comment: @Vux you have to tokenize that string first, then. Use `words`.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific test case this should work:

```
function [(x:' ':y:' ':o:_)] = (read [x], read [y], o)
```

If your string contains spaces you need to match on them as well if you want to do it like that.

But that's probably not what you actually want. It would break for inputs like `["12 23 S"]` or `["3 5 W", "2 8 E"]`.

If your input is actually a list of Strings like your signature says you should probably write two functions: One that deals with a single String and one that applies your other function to all Strings in the list. Look at the functions `map` and `words` and think about how you can use them to solve your problem.

Comment: Ah I see, the spaces are also part of the list. Thank you very much for that first part. As for the second, I think I see what you mean. In the case of ["12 23 S"], x wouldn't be 12, but 1, correct? I wasn't taking this into account, but you are right. So the input would actually be `function [(x:xs):' ':(y:ys):' ':o:_)` ?

Comment: Not quite. That pattern wouldn't work because (x:xs) matches on a whole List/String, and you can't have a String in a List of Chars. Really, look at the function `words`.

Comment: I have managed to get the function working. I didn't use the `map` function because I couldn't figure out how to get the answer, but it probably would have made my code a lot more elegant. Considering the input was always going to be of two numbers and a letter, I used the `words` function and then played around with heads and tails of the resulting list. Thank you for your help, regardless, as without it I wouldn't have solved this problem :).